# WooCommerce: how to run JS code after review order and payment method sections are Ajax refreshed?

Tags: woocommerce

On checkout page, I need to dynamically modify the content of the "review your order" section. Which is tricky because it's Ajax-loaded. How to run JS code after this Ajax load or reload, while making sure it'll run after not before it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Listen for the [`updated_checkout`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js#L323) trigger. Something like this might work:

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'updated_checkout', function() {
  console.log( 'checkout was updated' );
});
```

Comment: works like a charm :) But I'm really curious, how can I find this kind of thing myself?

Comment: The only suggestion I can give is to browse through the WooCommerce code base. The JS files just don't have the same documentation as the PHP ones does, if any. But, I know from experience that WC has many custom JS triggers, so it was just a matter of finding the correct one. For example, the link in the answer is to the `checkout.js` file which based on your question seemed like the place to start looking.

Comment: Neat, thanks Helga (just noticed you're a contributor too!)

Comment: Yup, I've sent them some bug-fixes. :)